# catchError doesnt exist on type (ret: any)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am upgrading from angular 4 to angular 6 app and having issues with the rxjs map function and rxjs Of operator. I know that you need to use pipepable operators but not sure why its still giving an error

Following is the function that i am trying to convert but it not syntactically right. Could you let me know where I am going wrong ?

```
    upload(url: string, body: any) {
            this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
            const stream = this._proxy.fileUpload(url, body).map(ret => ret.originalResponse).catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    this._userService.unauthorized();
                    return Observable.of(null);
                } else {
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                }
            });
            return stream;
        }
```

Modified code

```
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'; 
    import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';

         upload(url: string, body: any) {
        this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
        const stream = this._proxy.fileUpload(url, body).pipe(map((ret => ret.originalResponse).catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this._userService.unauthorized();
                return of(null);
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        })));
        return stream;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import of from RxJS and not operator

Import { of } from ‘rxjs’

Also, don’t chain catchError off of map, rather let it be a second param passed into pipe.

Comment: Sorry i had already done that and handnt updated my post. I am getting an issue with the catchError

Comment: Don’t chain off of map. Should map then a comma and then catchError